# TSQL: Query items which their max version is have state Failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL database with below rules:

- There are items with same name but different versions.
- Status of item production is stored inside a column `State`.

The structure of  table `log` inside `test` database is like below:

| id | Name | Ver | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | OK |
| 2 | B | 1 | Failed |
| 3 | C | 1 | OK |
| 4 | D | 1 | OK |
| 5 | A | 2 | OK |
| 6 | B | 2 | OK |
| 7 | C | 2 | Failed |
| 8 | D | 2 | OK |
| 9 | A | 3 | Failed |

According to our production rules, the last version made from an item should have state `OK` (not `Failed`). So I want a query to grab list of unacceptable items with below constraints:

- Name of items which their last version state is 'Failed'

In my sample data, the query should return `A` and `C` since Max version of `A` is 3 but its state is 'Failed' and max version of `C` is 2 but its state is `Failed`.

`B` and `D` are OK since their last version is 2 and the state of the version 2 for these items is `OK`.

How can I write query to bring list of items which their last version is failed (and not OK)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: for someone with >8k reputation you should surely know that images of data are frowned upon.

Comment: Take the duplicate, apply a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, yes, super rusty. Yet, you can definitely do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT mytable.name, mytable.ver, mytable.state 
from
(SELECT NAME, VER
FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME
HAVING VER = max(VER)) subq
INNER JOIN table on subq.name = mytable.name and subq.ver = mytable.ver
WHERE mytable.STATE = 'failed'
```

This is not a performant answer.

Comment: It will query the max version among the items where their state is 'FAILED'. I want to query Items which their max version row have status = 'FAILED'.

Comment: `HAVING VER = max(VER)` doesn't do anything, because you are grouping by `VER` anyway, and cannot take it out of the grouping

Comment: Fixed somewhat, I think.